# Is it inefficient to pass large objects as parameters in Java?

Tags: java, performance

Let's say for example I have a class A that creates an instance of a fairly big object B. Is passing B as a parameter to a method in a class C inefficient? 
That is, does it just pass a reference or does it shift the object's memory around as well?

Thanks.

Comment: brilliant question. Was about to ask the same thing and is nice to see the answers :) I was scared of passing all my objects about in parameters when I wanted a few pieces. Nice to see they're only references

Comment: All variables are primitives (up to 8 bytes) or references (also up to 8 bytes)  So it is not possible to pass more than 8 byte arguments to a method, and no this doesn't have a performance impact.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It just passes a reference. It's important to understand that the value of *any* expression in Java is *never* an object. It's only *ever* a reference or a primitive value.

This isn't just relevant for parameter passing - it's important to understand for return types, arrays, simple assignment etc.

Comment: So many times your answers helped me. Unfortunately, there is only 1 plus per post! Is there any suggestion from Jon Skeet about how to be programmer like Jon Skeet?

Comment: @jon, ignoring the efficiency, is it a good practice to pass the large object when only small amount of data is required?

Comment: @vardin: It makes no difference, because only a reference is being passed.

Comment: @vardin it's better to pass a large object rather than multiple small arguments

Comment: @ACV I wish I knew about this a couple of years back. I was asked by my code reviewer to re-write entire code just because I was passing the bulk object to a function(I was a fresher), which in her idea was making a new object clone everytime.

Answer (score 20):

Java can only pass two kinds of values to a method:

- primitive values (`int`, `char`, `double`, ...) or
- object references

There is no way you can pass a whole object "by value".

This means that you don't need to worry about "how big" your object is that you "pass around".

Answer (score 7):

It's not inefficient, because only the object reference is passed to the method.

Answer (score 5):

As long as your calls are local (same JVM) object size should not matter, however when your application uses remote calls like RMI /  Web Service (across JVMs) the large objects are capable of slowing down your application to a great extent because of huge amount of data that will be marshalled / unmarshalled and the network latency involved for every remote call.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, in Java you only have pass-by-value.  These values are only primitives and references. The largest a primitive or reference can be is 8-bytes. IMHO, there is no such thing as a large argument.

Comment: so you see here where the confusion comes from? On one side you say the reference gets passed and then you say you have pass-by-value. Of course it's a misnomer, but that's how it is

Comment: @ACV Java only has two variable types, primitives and references. Both primitives and references are always passed by value.

Comment: thanks - that's what I say - it should be called pass-by-reference-value. People imply that pass-by-value means pass the value that the reference points to, but that's not the case. It's the reference itself that gets passed. The value of the reference, not the value the reference points to

Comment: @ACV I think we are saying the same thing. I find there is an assumption that a `StringBuilder` variable is a string object, so passing by value must mean it is copied, but it is the reference which copied.

Comment: sure we are. I just find the name confusing. Or is it only me?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like memory Shifting.. it just passes the actual reference.. and the reference word itself stands for some address.. so no issue.. its efficient than parameter passing which really makes code more complex.. may be thats why SUN added it to java...

Answer (score 1):

It just pass a reference as value.

Answer (score 1):

Java passes references to objects *by value*. It makes no difference performance-wise whether the object reference being passed to C is big or not.